# Why doesn't ng-class evaluate unless the input is modified manually?

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-class

I've got an `textarea` input which is bound to a model. I also have a select which has an `ng-change` which fires a scope function. When one changes the select, the model is changed. The function on `ng-class` is comparing the original value of the model with the current value. The class which is added is used to color the background of the `textarea` such that when the the current value == original value the background is white. But there is something odd at play here.

Case 1:

1. Run the fiddle
2. Select ‘2017-10-12’ in the select box. The `select` background goes green (as intended) but the `textarea` background remains white.

Case 2:

1. Run the fiddle
2. Click into the `textarea` and change the value. The `textarea` goes green as intended. Typing the original value causes the `textarea` to go white as intended.
3. Choose ‘2017-10-12’ in the `select` box. The `select` background goes green AND the `textarea` goes green as well. (as intended)
4. Choose ‘2017-11-01’ in the `select` box. The select background goes white AND the `textarea` goes white as well. (as intended)

Why doesn't case #1 work?

See the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kSg_3KnwpC/evmt2c56/)

Comment: Using version 1.5.7 though the fiddle is 1.4.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's about the dirty checking and your CSS around it:

```
.form-control.ng-dirty.ng-valid, select.ng-dirty.ng-valid {
  background-color: $formDirtyValid;
}

.form-control.ng-dirty.ng-valid.nochange, select.ng-dirty.ng-valid.nochange {
  background-color: $formBack ;
}
```

Input elements will only have a class "ng-dirty" on it after you changed the input.

you could fix it by removing the ".ng-dirty" class selector from all css selectors, like so:

```
.form-control.ng-valid, select.ng-valid {
  background-color: $formDirtyValid;
}

.form-control.ng-valid.nochange, select.ng-valid.nochange {
  background-color: $formBack ;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/evmt2c56/15/